# Comparisson of addresses in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I have a situation where i'd like to fulfill array with elements that are not duplicates ( set alike ), so I wrote simple function in order to compare addresses before insertion.

Function is quite simple, but it doesn't work, so I have to ask for help...thanks in advance.

```
// function to prevent insertion of duplicates in array
function isDuplicate() public view returns (bool){
    for(uint i = 0; i < addressIndices.length; i++){
        if(addressIndices[i] == msg.sender) return true;
        else return false;
  }
}
```

In order to achieve completness of question, I''ll provide you more information:

First: Main structures:

```
struct Match{
    bytes32 teamHome;
    bytes32 teamAway;
    uint teamHomeGoals;
    uint teamAwayGoals;
    uint  oddsTeamHome;
    uint  oddsTeamAway;
    uint  oddsDraw;
    uint outcome; // outcome of a match ( possible values: '1', 'X', '2', mapped to, because of uint, as: '1', '2', '3');
}
struct Bet{
    address bettor; // address a of creator of a bet;
    bytes32 name; // name in a relation with ^ a provided address;
    uint amount; // deposit on bet;
    uint bet; // match index being bet on;
    uint outcome; // bet placed on a outcome; defined as: '1', 'X', '2', mapped to, because of uint, as: '1', '2', '3';
```

Second: Function to place a bet.

```
function placeBet(bytes32 name, uint _outcome, uint desiredMatchIndex, uint _amount) public payable{
// find a way to store a bid in order to be easily searchable, in order to easily send money to winners;
    //   require(!roundEnd, "Interactions with contract are locked, be careful next time!");
    //   require(state == State.Active, "Betting is over, game have already started!");
      require(msg.value > 0, "It isn't possible to place a bet without a money ");
    if(!isDuplicate()){
        addressIndices.push(msg.sender);
    }
      existingBets[msg.sender].push(Bet({
          bettor: msg.sender,
          name: name,
          amount: _amount,
          bet: desiredMatchIndex,
          outcome: _outcome
      }));
    // emit event, finally;
}
```

The problem is really weird: 
After I make 3 bets with 3 different addresses, length of my array that i am trying to use as a set, is 7. If function worked, it should be 3, if not it should be 9.

Any idea?

Edit: isDuplicate() function works only for first inserted address

Comment: The length of which array is 7? You append to `existingBets` no matter what `isDuplicate()` returns, so the length of that array should be the number of times `placeBet()` was called. The length of `addressIndices` should be the number of unique addresses that placed a bet.

Comment: Much easier would be a mapping: `mapping(address => bool) used;` and then `require(!used[msg.sender]); used[msg.sender] = true;` at the top of `placeBet()`. (This is assuming you _don't_ actually want to add to `existingBets` when `msg.sender` is a duplicate.)

Comment: @smarx 
First of all, thanks for effort, I really appreciate it! 
Yes, the length of addressIndices should be the number of unique addresses that placed a bet. 

Thanks for pointing out to an easier solution, but, at the end I'd need to keep track of length of unique addresses, in order to send payout to all of winners ( not sure if that's most optimal scenario, but I have to start with something).

Comment: So, basically, your approach makes sense, but I would need to keep track of length of suggested mapping as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current function never looks beyond the first element of the array. It returns either `true` or `false` immediately. Try this instead, but as I noted in my comment, a `mapping` would let you avoid the iteration:

```
// function to prevent insertion of duplicates in array
function isDuplicate() public view returns (bool) {
    for(uint i = 0; i < addressIndices.length; i++){
        if(addressIndices[i] == msg.sender) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: (This is assuming you don't actually want to add to existingBets when msg.sender is a duplicate.) 
I gave it a thought, and realized that it's not my use case - I'll add it in existingBets anyways ( no matter is it duplicate address or not ), but won't add it in addressIndices because i have to use that array in order to keep track of addresses count. 
@smarx
It's my fault, however, because I haven't provided enough information.
( mapping(address => Bet[]) public existingBets; )
Much gratitude for your assistance! : )